# Leaflet->how to draw a polygon with reference to another geographical position

Tags: leaflet, geometry

I have a basic leaflet map in which I draw a circle representing a city. 
Next, I would like to locate a rectangle with reference to that circle. (more specifically drawing a rectangle not with reference to its centroid or any corner x,y; but with reference to the circles x,y. So, I need to define the distance with these two objects, and dimensions of rectangle.)

Please see the image below as a graphical expression of this issue:

[image]

Comment: And your question is? I find your description hard to understand, and I do not understand what you are trying to do, and what the issue is

Comment: My question was how to draw the rectangle according to circle's location?

Comment: "draw the rectangle according to circle's location" is imprecise

Answer (score 0):

```
var position = new L.Rectangle(new L.Circle([x, y], R).getBounds().addTo(map);
```